# How I can solve this TypeError please?

Tags: json, python-3.x, django-views

I am following a tutorial from codeenterpreneur. I am trying to return data defined in the tweet_list_view funtion but somehow I got a TypeError. This is code:

```
def tweet_list_view(request, tweet_id, *args, **kwargs):
    '''
    rest API
    consume by javascripts or swift ios/Android
    return json data
    '''
qs = Tweet.objects.all()

tweet_list = [{'id': x.id, 'content': x.content} for x in qs]
data = {
    "response": tweet_list,
}
return JsonResponse(data)
```

This is the error I am getting

```
TypeError at /tweets/
tweet_list_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tweet_id'
```

Comment: your function requires a request and a tweet id, how is your calling code passing the tweet id?

Comment: You assign parameter 'tweet_id' but do not use. So remove it.

Comment: I remove it and it's works just fine, thanks Samsul Islam.